# Generate a row number for each entry in a pandas grouped dataframe when all rows in each group are the same

Tags: pandas, numpy

I have a data frame:

```
Test = pd.DataFrame([['US','CA', 'Los Angles', 10], ['US','IL', 'Springfield', 20]], 
         columns = ['country', 'state', 'city', 'counter'])
```

I want to repeat each row the number of times that is in the counter so I use `numpy`.

```
pet = pd.DataFrame(np.repeat(Test.values, Test['counter'].values, axis = 0), columns = Test.columns)
```

now how do I add a row number to each group?
So it should run `0 to 9` for Los Angles and `0 - 19` for Springfield

```
Result = pet.groupby(['country', 'state', 'city'])
Result['row_number'] = ??
```

I tried group by and saw examples of using rank but I don't think that works given that all my rows are the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need [`cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html):

```
pet['row_number'] = pet.groupby(['country', 'state', 'city']).cumcount()
print (pet) 
   country state         city counter  row_number
0       US    CA   Los Angles      10           0
1       US    CA   Los Angles      10           1
2       US    CA   Los Angles      10           2
3       US    CA   Los Angles      10           3
4       US    CA   Los Angles      10           4
5       US    CA   Los Angles      10           5
6       US    CA   Los Angles      10           6
7       US    CA   Los Angles      10           7
8       US    CA   Los Angles      10           8
9       US    CA   Los Angles      10           9
10      US    IL  Springfield      20           0
11      US    IL  Springfield      20           1
12      US    IL  Springfield      20           2
13      US    IL  Springfield      20           3
14      US    IL  Springfield      20           4
15      US    IL  Springfield      20           5
16      US    IL  Springfield      20           6
17      US    IL  Springfield      20           7
18      US    IL  Springfield      20           8
19      US    IL  Springfield      20           9
20      US    IL  Springfield      20          10
21      US    IL  Springfield      20          11
22      US    IL  Springfield      20          12
23      US    IL  Springfield      20          13
24      US    IL  Springfield      20          14
25      US    IL  Springfield      20          15
26      US    IL  Springfield      20          16
27      US    IL  Springfield      20          17
28      US    IL  Springfield      20          18
29      US    IL  Springfield      20          19
```